# Can this scenario be called SAAS

Tags: saas

I wanted to know if this scenario falls under the SAAS category. If not what is it?

1. I have a win-forms application (.Net).
2. I subscribe for a windows virtual machine, which i will manage (on azure or AWS)
3. I then put my win-forms application on the Virtual machine
4. provide users remote desktop access to the cloud environment where the win-forms app is.
5. the user double clicks the app to run it..

Comment: anyone? would be great to even get personal opinions

Comment: It might be "great".  But it is off-topic.  Please don't ask questions that you know are outside of the scope of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote 'yes': it satisfies the two requirements.  A) it is software and B) it is being provided as a service.  The end user's liability is limited to paying any subscription that may be asked for.  Whether or not you also provide support and/or a knowledge base is not relevant to the definition, although they're bound to be factors in the viability of the service.  Your offering may not deserve to see the light of day, but it's still SaaS.